# problemas de envio de correo desde PHP en el servidor godaddy

Tags: php

Tengo el siguiente codio y no envia el correo

```
require 'PHPMailer/class.phpmailer.php';
    require 'PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

    //Create a new PHPMailer instance
        $mail = new PHPMailer();
        $mail->IsSMTP();
        $mail->From = "correo@gmail.com"; //remitente
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
        $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
        $mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
        $mail->Port = 465;
        $mail->Username ='correo@gmail.com'; //nombre usuario
        $mail->Password = 'contraseña'; //contraseña
        $mail->Mailer = "smtp";
        $mail->AddAddress($email);
        $mail->Subject = $asunto;
        $mail->Body = $cuerpo;
        if($mail->send())
        return true;
        else
        return false;
```

me muestra el siguiente error: ya realice los cambios y me muestra el siguiente error:

> SMTP connect() failed.
> github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting

Comment: Por el error que indicas, tendrás que añadir la class.phpmailer.php y PHPMailerAutoload.php, puedes obtenerlos de https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer

Comment: creo que gmail es `tls` y el puerto es `587` y aceptar el acceso para aplicaciones poco seguras, como la notificacion de inicio de session en X dispositivo o ip, en todo caso validar con `$mail->SMTPDebug=2;` y en tu condicion cambia `return false` por `echo "Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;`

Comment: ya realice los cambios y me muestra el siguiente error: SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting

Comment: Puede ser que GoDaddy no quiere que nadie envie correo por PHP para prevenir spam?

Comment: @Duston no ...  nadie alquilaría sus servidores entonces

Comment: este problema esta asociado a las credenciales y autenticación del usuario que envía el correo; debes validar si son correctos los datos y si la configuración del método de conexión es la adecuada para conectar con godaddy.

Comment: lamentablemente no podemos reproducir este problema.

Comment: La contraseña es un application password en la cuenta gmail usada? Si usas la contraseña de iniciar sesión, te va a pedir OAuth y va a fallar...

Comment: Después de `$mail = new PHPMailer();` coloca la linea: `$mail->SMTPDebug = 1;` y mira a ver qué error te sale.