# problema en el envió de correo con php en maquina de Amazon

Tags: php, aws

estoy haciendo un formulario en php en el que al enviarlo debería llegarme un correo con los datos del formulario rellenados, de manera local me funcionaba bien y al subirlo a otro servidor tambien envia los correos bien pero al hacerlo desde la máquina de aws no me llega nada, que es lo que podría estar mal??

```
<?php
include("con_db.php");

if(isset($_POST['registrar'])){
    $nombreContacto = trim($_POST['nombreContacto']);
    $cargoEmpresa = trim($_POST['cargoEmpresa']);
    $nombreEmpresa = trim($_POST['nombreEmpresa']);
    $direccion = trim($_POST['direccion']);
    $telefono = trim($_POST['telefono']);
    $email = trim($_POST['email']);
    $producto = trim($_POST['producto']);
    $cantidad = trim($_POST['cantidad']);
    $comentarios = trim($_POST['comentarios']);
    $fechareg = date("d/m/y");
    $Producto = "SELECT productos from producto Where num = $producto";
    $Producto1 = mysqli_query($conex, $Producto);
    $Producto2 = mysqli_fetch_array($Producto1);

    if($cantidad > 99){
        $costo = "SELECT producto.costo from producto Where producto.productos = '$Producto2[0]'";
        $costo1 = mysqli_query($conex, $costo);
        $costo2 = mysqli_fetch_array($costo1);
    }
    else{
        $costo = "SELECT producto.costo1 from producto Where producto.productos = '$Producto2[0]'";
        $costo1 = mysqli_query($conex, $costo);
        $costo2 = mysqli_fetch_array($costo1);
    }
    $valor = $cantidad * $costo2[0];

    $contenido = "Nombre Contacto: ". $nombreContacto .
    "\nCargo en empresa: ". $cargoEmpresa .
    "\nNombre de la Empresa: ". $nombreEmpresa .
    "\nDireccion: ". $direccion .
    "\nTelefono: ". $telefono .
    "\nEmail: ". $email .
    "\nProducto: ". $Producto2[0] .
    "\nCantidad: ". $cantidad .
    "\nCosto: ". $valor .
    "\nComentarios: ". $comentarios .
    "\nFecha de envio del formulario: ". $fechareg .
    "\n";
    $destino = "rodrigomunita14@gmail.com";

    $header = "From: noreply@upcycling.com" . "\r\n";
    $header .= "Reply-To: noreply@upcycling.com" . "\r\n";
    $header .= "X-Mailer: PHP/". phpversion();

    if($cantidad > 49){
        mail($destino,"Formulario Upcycling",$contenido,$header);
    }
```

Comment: Otra persona ha puesto una pregunta semejante (pero ya no hay respuestas) https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/497798/problemas-de-envio-de-correo-desde-php-en-el-servidor-godaddy?noredirect=1#comment884983_497798

Comment: puedes adjuntar el código fuente, así es más fácil ayudarte

Comment: en el servidor la función mail() esta activa?

Comment: creo que esta desactivada, encontre una pagina en la que dicen que ahora amazon tiene desactivada esa funcion, estoy buscando una forma de activarla pero no la encuentro

Comment: Para AWS te recomiendan instalar y usar PHPMailer [enlace](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/send-using-smtp-php.html)